# Splitting large chunks of text with a regex in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, logging, split

I've got a lot of text I want to split. It's tough because it's all technically one line. The text is unformatted logged messages from a network device - the only way to tell where one message starts and one message ends is that a message always begins with `'.{5}\d{7}'` such as `<186>1093281`. How can I read in that string, kept in a file called "textLog" and split it based on that regex to form a new string/array for clean output?

Example Input:

```
<189>795307: Aug  8 11:41:38 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-POWER_GRANTED: Interface Gi1/0/8: Power granted<189>795308: Aug  8 11:41:39 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-IEEE_DISCONNECT: Interface Gi1/0/8: PD removed<189>795309: Aug  8 11:41:45 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-POWER_GRANTED: Interface Gi1/0/8: Power granted<189>795310: Aug  8 11:41:46 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-IEEE_DISCONNECT: Interface Gi1/0/8: PD removed<189>795311: Aug  8 11:41:52 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-POWER_GRANTED: Interface Gi1/0/8: Power granted<189>795312: Aug  8 11:41:53 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-IEEE_DISCONNECT: Interface Gi1/0/8: PD removed<189>795313: Aug  8 11:41:59 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-IEEE_DISCONNECT: Interface Gi1/0/8: PD removed<189>795314: Aug  8 11:42:05 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-POWER_GRANTED: Interface Gi1/0/8: Power granted
```

(It is formatted as one long string rather than multiple lines.)

Desired output: an array containing...

```
arr[0]=<189>795307: Aug  8 11:41:38 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-POWER_GRANTED: Interface Gi1/0/8: Power granted
arr[1]=<189>795308: Aug  8 11:41:39 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-IEEE_DISCONNECT: Interface Gi1/0/8: PD removed
arr[2]=<189>795309: Aug  8 11:41:45 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-POWER_GRANTED: Interface Gi1/0/8: Power granted
...
arr[7]=<189>795314: Aug  8 11:42:05 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-POWER_GRANTED: Interface Gi1/0/8: Power granted
```

It doesn't have to be an array or stored in a data structure, I'm mostly concerned with the method to split based on the regex for either outputting or saving the substring.

Comment: Does a message actually begin with `<\d{3}>\d{7}` as in your example, rather than the more generic `.{5}\d{7}`?

Comment: @blhsing You're correct, I just couldn't get the more specific one to work for me with grep (bit of a novice) so i settled for the more lax version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed and Bash 4.0 or newer:

```
$ mapfile -t arr < <(sed -E 's/(.)(.{5}[[:digit:]]{6})/\1\n\2/g' infile)
$ printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
<189>795307: Aug  8 11:41:38 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-POWER_GRANTED: Interface Gi1/0/8: Power granted
<189>795308: Aug  8 11:41:39 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-IEEE_DISCONNECT: Interface Gi1/0/8: PD removed
<189>795309: Aug  8 11:41:45 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-POWER_GRANTED: Interface Gi1/0/8: Power granted
<189>795310: Aug  8 11:41:46 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-IEEE_DISCONNECT: Interface Gi1/0/8: PD removed
<189>795311: Aug  8 11:41:52 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-POWER_GRANTED: Interface Gi1/0/8: Power granted
<189>795312: Aug  8 11:41:53 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-IEEE_DISCONNECT: Interface Gi1/0/8: PD removed
<189>795313: Aug  8 11:41:59 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-IEEE_DISCONNECT: Interface Gi1/0/8: PD removed
<189>795314: Aug  8 11:42:05 EDT: %ILPOWER-5-POWER_GRANTED: Interface Gi1/0/8: Power granted
```

The sed command looks for any chunk of 6 (and not 7, as implied in the question) digits preceded by 6 characters, and inserts a newline after the first character. This excludes the string matching at the beginning of the line, where we don't want to introduce a newline.

`mapfile` then reads the result into the array `arr` by means of process substitution. The `printf` statement shows the array elements one per line.

Alternatively, based on the example input, you could use grep to split into lines as follows:

```
grep -o '<[^<]*' infile
```

This assumes that every occurrence of `<` marks a new log line.